# Cannot create a new project in unreal engine 4

Tags: xcode, mono, unreal-engine4

Before this error occurred i was receiving another error notifying me that unreal cannot detect a c++ compiler and to install Xcode even after installing Xcode. I've installed multiple version and that has seem to address that issue for now. However, I am now receiving a different error. I have tried many solutions such as export to the directory from terminal however no luck.

```
An error occurred while trying to generate project files.


Running Mono...

Found mono via known Mono.framework path
Running installed mono, version:  Mono JIT compiler version 6.4.0.208 (2019-06/07c23f2ca43 Wed Oct 2 04:52:23 EDT 2019)
/Applications/GameDev/UE_4.21/Engine /Applications/GameDev/UE_4.21/Engine/Binaries/Mac
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
Generating data for project indexing...
Triggered an exception while looking for SDK directory in Xcode.app

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs'.
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1[TResult].CreateDirectoryHandle (System.String path, System.Boolean ignoreNotFound) [0x00032] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1[TResult]..ctor (System.String directory, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00048] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1+DelegateEnumerator[TResult]..ctor (System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1[TResult] enumerable) [0x00000] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1[TResult]..ctor (System.String directory, System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1+FindTransform[TResult] transform, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00042] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserDirectories (System.String directory, System.String expression, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00014] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchTarget searchTarget, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00045] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.EnumerationOptions enumerationOptions) [0x00000] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories (System.String path) [0x0000b] in <ba70b91736bd40cb990a357097dba9c3>:0 
  at UnrealBuildTool.AppleToolChainSettings.SelectSDK (System.String BaseSDKDir, System.String OSPrefix, System.String& PlatformSDKVersion, System.Boolean bVerbose) [0x0001d] in <782077b94fec4538a544b9c45478bfa6>:0

WARNING: Exception while generating include data for UE4Editor: Invalid SDK MacOSX.sdk, not found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
WARNING: Exception while generating include data for MyProjectEditor: Invalid SDK MacOSX.sdk, not found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
Writing project files...
Writing project files... 0%
ERROR: UnrealBuildTool Exception: Invalid SDK MacOSX.sdk, not found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
```